# Java Moving Files

Tags: java

Right now, I'm trying to move files and folders from a directory onto my Desktop. Currently here's my code:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.FileUtils;

class CopyDirectoryApache {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File sourceLocation = new File("/home/jakobcurrin/minecraft/mods/");
    File targetLocation = new File("/home/jakobcurrin/desktop/");

    FileUtils.copyDirectory(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
  }
}

Main.java:6: error: class CopyDirectory is public, should be declared in a 
file named CopyDirectory.java
public class CopyDirectory
       ^
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import java.nio.FileUtils;
               ^
  symbol:   class FileUtils
  location: package java.nio
2 errors
```

I debugged the code, and it keeps saying "Cannot find symbol." How can I fix this? If you could explain thoroughly, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*
```

This should fix your problem. Just remove the 'n' and use a different library.
The class `File` ([Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)) has some pretty good methods for file operations.

`isDirectory()` lets you check if your path is correct.

On the other hand you could use this method:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*; 
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The method copies all files from `source` to `target`.

Comment: I'm now having problems importing FileUtils? Using Java 8, with the command ```import java.nio.FileUtils```. Does that look right @JustAProgrammer?

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors.

The first: `Main.java:6: error: class CopyDirectory is public, should be declared in a 
file named CopyDirectory.java` is because the file's name is different to the class' name.

And the second is because you don't have the dependency or library [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)

Comment: How do I fix that @Alvaro?

Comment: do you use someone IDE?

Comment: No. Right now I'm actually using Google's free Terminal since I'm having issues with my normal computer

Comment: Maybe you create a project, Ant project for example and after add the necessary dependencies. A guide for it https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html